# Haskell filter function laziness

Tags: haskell

Given:

```
take 5 (filter p xs)
```

say if `filter p xs` would return 1K match, would Haskell only filter out 5 matches and without producing a large intermediate result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will scan `xs` only as much as needed to produce 5 matches, evaluating `p` only on this prefix of `xs`.

To be more precise, it can actually perform less computation, depending on how the result is used. For instance,

```
main = do
   let p x = (x==3) || (x>=1000000)
       list1 = [0..1000000000]
       list2 = take 5 (filter p list1)
   print (head list2)
```

will only scan `list1` until `3` is found, and no more, despite `take` asking for five elements. This is because `head` is demanding only the first of these five, so laziness causes to evaluate just that.

Answer (score 4):

"Would return 1K matches" under what circumstances?

Haskell doesn't work by first evaluating `filter p xs` (as you would in an ordinary call-by-value language like Java or Ruby).  It works by evaluating `take 5` first (in this case).  `take 5` will evaluate enough of `filter p xs` to end up with a result, and not evaluate the rest.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily evaluate even (take 5 ...) first, it depends on how that value is used.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will not.

If it does, something like the following would not work anymore

```
take 5 (filter (> 10) [1..])
```

This feature is called [Lazy evaluation](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Lazy_evaluation).